# Paypal Giving CODE: 10002. Restricted account. Account is restricted

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I recently took the Alidropship plugin and created my site (www.anamee.com). I opted for Business PayPal and updated all the required information regarding the API signature in the Alidropship plugin in WordPress site. All the API details are entered and in the plugin it shows Active. I also see PayPal option for purchase on the site.

However, I am getting error when I am trying to make payment on the site via PayPal. When I checked, Alidropship log files indicate below details.

> CODE: 10002. Restricted account. Account is restricted.

I researched on the PayPal and found that we need to enter a username as per this [article](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1432)

Checked with their Alidropship support, they stated that no one ever asked for username and that it is not required.

Few things about my PayPal account.

1. Created 2 days back.
2. Already added the PAN Card and verified
3. Added my Indian Bank Account and Debit Card - but still PayPal notification says Please confirm your identity to avoid any service interruptions.
4. I used this account to purchase also
5. But couldn't withdraw from other PayPal account
6. I also get this note :

   > By adding a bank account you can receive funds and withdraw it. Once you add a Bank account, PayPal will send two small deposits to the bank account within 3-5 business days. Please log in to your PayPal account, and enter the two amounts to lift your sending and withdrawal limit.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is sorted out.

There are few things that needs to be updated when we open the PayPal account, like for India - PAN, Bank Account, Purpose Code.

Strange thing is that I entered all the details, they were even showing up. Still I was prompted that Bank and Identification ( PAN ) details are missing. It was also stating that the when you add a Bank account some amount will be transferred in 3-5 days and that will complete the updation.

I reached out the PayPal support line and the rep was great enough to find all the required information is updated in the account already, hence she cleared the limitation from the backend. And that cleared the error and now payments can be made via PayPal.

NOTE: Indian users with their address in India cannot purchase via PayPal as of now and hence I have to find another payment gateway.

Closing this Question!

Best,
Santosh

Comment: Looks like I cannot close this question. Kinda strange that I need some points to close my question which is now with an answer. Leaving it for the Stackflow.